# Queue and "timeout" async functions calls in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I am making a API client for my react web app with mobx, which can query the server with keywords for search results.

Now in order to make the user experience better, I want to implement an instant search feature like Google's search box, which keeps sending the server queries and update the search results constantly.

Right now, I am naively sending a new request to the server every time the input field's state changes. However this is not very efficient and might blow up the server if the user is typing a long query very fast. A 30 character search query will send 30 requests to the server, and if I don't await those requests to resolve on the client side sequentially, the end result delivered to the search result field is not guaranteed to be the correct one. (when a previous request resolves later than latest request)

Is there a good way and strategy to "queue" the search calls, only firing a new request on top of the queue in say 200ms, and timeout/abandon all other search calls that's obsolete? Maybe also send a request when the user stops typing for 50ms.

So say the user types his/her query in 300ms, then there'll be 2 calls only: first one is the half finished query 200ms after he/she started tying, the second one is at 350ms, 50ms after he/she ended typing.

For example:

```
// the search function that I want to queue
async function searchFor(term) {
  return await client('search', term) 
}

// the event handler for input field updates
async function handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({term: event.target.value})
  await queryEnqueue(() => searchFor(event.target.value)) // the function that I'm looking for
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for the term `debounce`. Check out this [link](https://medium.com/@platonish/debouncing-functions-in-react-components-d42f5b00c9f5)

Comment: why you don't try this with RxJS ?

Comment: @AndreiTodorut I haven't learnt RxJS yet. :(

Comment: RxJS is a heavyweight aproach. It's reasonably simple to concoct something with `setTimeout()` / `clearTimeout()`.